# Change legend shape size for fill using geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Here is my reproducible code:**

This is an example of what I want my actual figure to look like.

```
library(tidyverse)
p <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(carb)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = cyl)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Red","Green","Blue"))
```

**Resulting figure:**
[image: Example histogram]

**Problem:**

What I want to change is in the legend. The boxes depicting the color of the bars on the histogram are too big and I want to reduce the size.

**Attempted Solutions:**

I have tried this code from another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469757/change-the-shape-of-legend-key-for-geom-bar-in-ggplot2) and it does not work:

```
p <- p + guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(width = .5)))
```

In the reference stackoverflow question, another user suggested making a dummy geom_point variable and then using that legend as the legend and removing the fill legend. I would rather not have to do that if possible.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `legend.key.size` (or `legend.key.height` and `legend.key.width`). E.g., add

```
theme(legend.key.size = unit(0.1, "cm"))
```

to your plot

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!