# Why can't I change the shape of the fill legend box?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been struggling to change my fill legend shape from squares to circles. I just tried to replicate this issue in a vanilla rstudio.cloud environment, and it still isn't working:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tigris)
options(tigris_class = "sf")
options(tigris_use_cache = TRUE)

df_ohio <- counties(state = "OH", cb = T, resolution = "20m") %>%
  mutate(defiance = if_else(NAME == "Defiance", 1, 0)) 

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = df_ohio, color = "black", 
          aes(fill = as.factor(defiance)), size = .1, alpha = .75) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#BB0000','navy'),
                    labels = c('No','Yes'),
                    name = "Defiance County?") +
  theme_void() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 20)))
```

When I try this I still get the result below, which has the fill legend shape as squares (shape 15, I guess) instead of circles (shape 20) like I specified. Any ideas?

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

You could add a layer of `geom_point` without data just to create a legend, and then set `show.legend = F` in the `geom_sf` layer to hide the squares, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40470301/7705000):

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = df_ohio, color = "black", aes(fill = as.factor(defiance)), size = .1, alpha = .75, show.legend = F) +
  geom_point(data = df_ohio, aes(x = -83, y = 40, color = as.factor(defiance)), size=8, alpha = 0) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('#BB0000','navy'),
                    labels = c('No','Yes'),
                    name = "Defiance County?") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#BB0000','navy')) + 
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1))) +
  theme_void()
```

Within the `geom_point` layer you can change the shape with `override.aes`, but the default is a circle as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the legend shape if you are working with points rather than polygons. Fortunately, `geom_sf` allows you to override the default and use point for legend, even if the underlying geom is a polygon, by specifying `show.legend = "point"`.

Demonstration with a built-in dataset:

```
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)

ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA >= 0.15), show.legend = "point") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#BB0000','navy'),
                    labels = c('No','Yes'),
                    name = "Defiance County?") +
  theme_void() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21, size = 5)))
```

[image: result plot]

(Since it's used in fill, shape 21 seems more appropriate than shape 20; I've also increased the size for ease of view.)